# Baffled by CSS positioning of span in div

Tags: css, positioning, html

I am trying to style a div to have heading area with text and graphics. When I add an svg element, the position of span element is no longer where I specify. I am positioning span as relative in order to pad it at the top.

Here is the js-fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fZTm7/3/

I expected the second *div* to look just like the first with *Bar* replaced with the svg rectangle.

I also see that the amount of displacement of *span* from its expected position gets smaller as I reduce the height of svg element. This is completely baffling. Since I see the same behavior in chrome and firefox, I am sure there is some css rule that is being broken.

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `float: left` on both the span and the svg. See: http://jsfiddle.net/fZTm7/10/

Comment: While floating the content renders it correctly, my question is still unanswered. Do you have any idea why the weird placement is happening?

Comment: span is an inline element by default, and will be aligning itself with the baseline of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `vertical-align: top;` to the `.panel-hdg` class for the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `float: left` property for SVG tag will fix the alignment issue. You do not need to add for `.panel-hdg` class.

```
svg{float: left;}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fZTm7/27

**Now back to your comment on @Logan Serman's answer:**
It is a thumb rule for any element to use FLOAT property while to align element side-by-side to each other.

In your case, there are SPAN and SVG tags. SPAN is an INLINE element and there is nowhere specified that how SVG behaves physically - INLINE/BLOCK. So floating is the only property here to fix.